# как к loopback интерфейсу по ssh подключится

Tags: администрирование

Можно через ssh к loopback интерфейсу на роутере подключится и настроить роутер?
И loopback интерфейсы используются для проверки сети? Например Есть ping или нет, так как это интерфейс всегда up, и loopback'ов можно сколько угодно делать

Comment: loopback обычно только внутри хоста маршрутизируется. снаружи к нему нельзя подключиться. Так что и по ssh через него можно подключиться только если вы уже зашли на роутер через другой интерфейс

Comment: Спасибо, а про то что loopback интерфейсы используются для проверки сети? Например Есть ping или нет, так как это интерфейс всегда up, и loopback'ов можно сколько угодно делать . Правильно?

Comment: Ну опять же это делать бессмысленно, только убедиться что сеть внутри машины впринципе жива, loopback поднят (и да, он поднимается при загрузке системы как все остальные интерфейсы, может и не быть up теоретически, хотя так никто и не делает) и какой нибудь фаервол что нибудь не режет. Снаружи опять же доступа к нему не будет. Его основное назначение что бы программы рассчитанные на работу через сеть могли работать между собой внутри хоста.